# Custom emmet snippets not working in vscode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, emmet

I am trying to set custom emmet snippets, but it is not working.

My **snippets.json** file

```
{
  "html": {
    "snippets": {
      "testing": "div{Hello World}"
    }
  }
}
```

My file is certainly 'HTML' format and I tried to relaunch vscode.
Also I checked that path to snippets.json is correct and it is visible in 'settings'.

Also tried with two different machines, same situation.

Here is **settings.json**

```
{
  "some other settings",
  "emmet.extensionsPath": ["D:\\FRONTEND\\snippets.json"]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `emmet.extensionsPath` takes a **directory** not a file path so try

`"emmet.extensionsPath": ["D:\\FRONTEND"]` instead

> #### Using custom Emmet snippets
>
> Custom Emmet snippets need to be defined in a json file named
> `snippets.json`. The `emmet.extensionsPath` setting should have the
> path to the directory containing this file.

- from [Using custom emmet snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets)

Comment: Oh my god, I am such a careless. I didn't see it in few guides that I dont need to set file path!!

Please, can somebody +1 to this answer, I dont have 15 reputation, only 11.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score -2):

Your syntax for the snippet is kinda wrong, here is the correct one, copy paste this:
***(you must modify the prefix as like you want)***

```
    "html": {
    "prefix":  ["div"],
    "body": "div{Hello World}",
    "description": "div"
    }
```

Comment: These are custom emmet snippets, they have a different syntax than regular snippets.  See the link above.