# How to configure emmet snippets.json for TSX files in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Thanks to the [Custom emmet snippets not working in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687012/custom-emmet-snippets-not-working-in-vscode) I figured out how to configure custom emmet snippets. It works good for the `*.html` files, but I can't achieve the same for the `*.tsx` files.

My `snippet.json` file looks like this: (you can see I tried every possible language id)

```
{
  "typescript": {
    "snippets": {
      "fm": "FormattedMessage[id]"
    }
  },
  "typescriptreact": {
    "snippets": {
      "fm": "FormattedMessage[id]"
    }
  },
  "javascript": {
    "snippets": {
      "fm": "FormattedMessage[id]"
    }
  },
  "javascriptreact": {
    "snippets": {
      "fm": "FormattedMessage[id]"
    }
  },
  "html": {
    "snippets": {
      "fm": "FormattedMessage[id]"
    }
  }
}
```

Despite that I can only access `fm` snippet in `*.html` files.

What should I change to be able to use this snippet in `*.tsx` files?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to File>Preferences>Configure User Snippets.

From there you can choose typescript.

Here is an example of my snippet:

```
{
  "Create div with className": {
    "prefix": ["c"],
    "body": ["<div className={styles."],
    "description": "Create div with className"
  }
}
```